# Recursion for binary search trees

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a good grip over recursive algorithms, however I usually stumble when designing recursive algorithms for binary search trees. If anyone could point to a tutorial they found useful, specifically on the design of recursive algorithms for binary search trees, it will be greatly appreciated.
Note: I have already studied this topic from well-known books including CLRS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need tutorials about design of recursive algorithms for binary search trees? Here they are:

- [Binary search tree - Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)
- [EBTree](http://1wt.eu/articles/ebtree/)
- [Binary Trees by Nick Parlante - Standford](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html)
- [Binary Search Trees - Princeton](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/)
- [Binary Search Tree C++ implementation](http://igushev.com/implementations/binary-search-tree-cpp/)
- [Binary Tree Traversals](http://nova.umuc.edu/~jarc/idsv/lesson1.html)
- [Balanced binary search tree on array](http://piergiu.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/balanced-binary-search-tree-on-array/)
- [Multidimensional Binary Search Trees Used for Associative Searching - Bentley](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~ad/MDE515/p509-bentley.pdf)
- [Priority search tree - E. McCreight - Princeton](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring04/cos423/handouts/priority%20search%20trees.pdf)

Anyway [Google](https://www.google.com/) is always a good friend for this type of questions.